# “The application does not have a valid signature” shows EVERY second time in XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, compilation, xcode5

I created new target for my app and every second time I compile it and try to run on the device, I get:

> “The application does not have a valid signature”

...and app does not run.

I checked all similar posts in stackoverflow but none of the solutions helped me (cleaning project, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found people saying two different things that are supposed to solve this problem:

- Delete all broken provisioning profiles.
- Ensure there are no spaces in the name of the folder that you are building from (your Xcode project folder) -- this was what fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Under **General** -> **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

Removing all the frameworks and relinking them was what worked for me.

Comment: Hey that one worked for me, especially on Xcode 8. I removed and added again all frameworks. In your general setting of your project, go to "Linked Frameworks and Libraries", delete them all and add them again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another possible cause:

In my case I had integrated SpeechKit (2.1.5) as a an embedded framework in an iOS Swift project and this somehow caused the error.

When I used Cocoa Pods the error didn't occur anymore.

Comment: I need the `embedded framework` running. How prevent thit, with that configuration?

Comment: @jose920405 is it a third-party framework? then you should report this to the developer/s because you're probably not alone with that problem

Answer (score 0):

Clean, deleted derived data, rebuild worked for me.